# Problema con slider y el SetInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

Buenas, espero me puedan ayudar con este pequeño problema

estoy probando hacer un slider con jquery y js, resulta que al darle a las imagenes un timer(setinterval) y su efecto FadeOut y FadeIn , todo trabaja perfecto, pero pasa algo que me parece que esta mal y no se solucionarlo

Resulta que al pasarme de pestaña en el navegador y mantenerme un tiempo fuera de la pagina donde esta el slider, al regresar a la pagina del slider, las imagenes comienzan a pasar a una velocidad exagerada como tratandome de mostrar todo lo que no me mostro durante el tiempo que no estuve presente, y luego se tranquiliza y vuelve a pasar las imagenes con la velocidad normal, ALGUIEN ME PODRIA AYUDAR?

actualmente solo estoy probando antes de iniciar con el proyecto y no quisiera lidiar con esto

aqui esta el link para que miren(Ignoren el orden del codigo, ya que es solo pruebas)

http://ombranding.esy.es/

Comment: Consulta, en que navegador estas probando?

Comment: estoy usando Google Chrome

Comment: ¿Que computador estas utilizando? Ya que he hecho varias veces la prueba y no me ha dado nada de problemas

Comment: @JoséMiguelSepulveda, puedes colocar el código en tu pregunta, sale click en [edit]. Mira [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78).

Comment: Creo que te equivocaste compañero xDDD

Comment: El problema no da siempre, sin embargo en una de las pruebas me ocurrió lo que comentas, es por ello que te recomiendo usar `clearInterval()`

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo antes de asignar el ID en `SliderInternal = setInterval(...)`  uses `clearInterval`.

Ejemplo:

```js
var SliderInit = function() {
  if (SliderInternal)
    clearInterval(SliderInternal);

  SliderInternal = setInterval(function changeSlider() {
    sliderPanel.eq(CurrentSlider).fadeOut('slow');
    sliderPanel.eq(nextSlider).fadeIn('slow');

    //actualizar datos
    if (nextSlider >= lengthSlider - 1) {
      nextSlider = 0;
      CurrentSlider = lengthSlider - 1;
    } else {
      //actualizar datos
      CurrentSlider = nextSlider;
      nextSlider += 1;
    }
    //console.log(nextSlider);

  }, dataInterval);
};
```

Comment: Me ha funcionado perfectamente, no sucedio de nuevo. Gracias.

Comment: Que bien!... me contenta que te haya servido y recuerda: califica la respuesta que se ajuste mas a una solución al problema, Saludos!! ;))...